# Linker error and unexpected run-time behavior when compiling C++ class library on RHEL

Tags: c++, linker, rhel8

I wrote a small C++ class library and driver program to run on RHEL, as a learning exercise.  When building the library, there is usually a linker error that I don't understand.  Trial and error shows that I can eliminate the error by limiting what I try to write using printf/fprintf (e.g. don't hard-code characters in the format string, and only use the %c conversion spec.)  When I run the driver in the form it allows me to build, the output looks suspiciously like it's not executing as coded.

Here are the commands I'm using to build:

```
libxor.so: xor.cpp
    g++ -c -o xor.o xor.cpp
    gcc -shared -o libxor.so xor.o

drv: drv.cpp libxor.so
    g++ -o drv drv.cpp -L/home/xxx/source -lxor
```

Here is the linker error:

```
g++ -c -o xor.o xor.cpp
gcc -shared -o libxor.so xor.o
/usr/bin/ld: xor.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:5: libxor.so] Error 1
```

Statements in drv.cpp to write output don't cause problems, only in xor.cpp.  The statements it allows me to include in xor.cpp without breaking the build look like:

```
printf("%c", plainText[curSubscript]);
```

If I put more in the format string, or use a different conversion spec, I get the linker error.  I'd appreciate any help with this, i.e. what is causing the linker error and why would the output of the program be possibly unexpected when I eliminate the linker error.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding `-fPIC` as the compiler suggests?

Comment: I just tried adding it to the initial compilation of the library.  I didn't try before because I wasn't sure at which point it should be added.  Now it looks like the linker errors are eliminated, but the output at run-time is still unexpected, so hopefully I can figure that out.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. If the output is unexpected, you probably have a bug.